# Run a script on save in textmate

Tags: textmate

I was wondering if it was possible to run a custom script on save based on certain file names in textmate. For example I'd like to auto compile a C program sometime on save.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually fairly easy to do this using a custom command in a bundle.

Here's how to make a simple command:

- Open up the bundle editor, and find the bundle you want to add to.
- Create a "New Command" using the button on the bottom left of the editor. Name it appropriately, and set its scope to `source.c`.
- Set the action dropdown to "Key Equivalent", and set the shortcut `Cmd + S`.
- Change the "Save" dropdown to "Current File".
- Enter your command, and set the input and output dropdowns appropriately. Input will be piped to STDIN if I remember correctly.
- Reload TextMate's bundles.

That's it. You should now have a command which saves the file, and runs a command.

You can probably do something with TextMate commands by using a macro in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this as you described, for all save situations (i.e., using Command-S, selecting File->Save, etc.).

You might be able to create a custom bundle item that saves the document and executes your script, and assign it Command-S, so that it runs when you use that keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

you can trigger a command after save via `callback.document.did-save` semantic class. This works on TextMate2+

Comment: Where does the semantic class can be added ? It can be useful when the save happens automatically and not by a key press.

Comment: Found it : that is one of the input of a command form.